# Simplifying $\int_0^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \, _2F_1\left(1,d;c+d+1;2-\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx$

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

I have been working on a statistics project that hinges on the following function.
$$
\int_0^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \, _2F_1\left(1,d;c+d+1;2-\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx$$
Is it all possible to remove the integral or make this easier to work with/compute? I'm very unfamiliar with hypergeometric functions, so since this popped out of my equations I've been pretty lost.

here 2F1 is the hypergeometric function

Comment: I decided to not include this for brevity, but what I'm looking to compute specifically is that function,  multiplied by $$\frac{c}{(c+d) B(a,b)}$$

Comment: Change variables $y=2-1/x$, $$\int_{0}^{1}\!{x}^{a-1} \left( 1-x \right) ^{b-1}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,d;\,c+d+1;\,2-1/x)}\,{\rm d}x\\=\int_{-\infty }
^{1}\!\left( -1 \right) ^{a+1} \left( y-2 \right) ^{-a-b} \left( y-1
 \right) ^{b-1}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,d;\,c+d+1;\,y)}\,{\rm d}y$$I don't find it in the tables.

Comment: Update: I've done some more investigating, and it turns out I can utilize some symmetries and you only need to evaluate the original integral between 1/2 and 1. or 0 to 1/2 So I can simplify your expression to
$\int_0^1 (1-y)^{b-1} (2-y)^{-a-b} \, _2F_1(1,d;c+d+1;y) \, dy$
or
$\int_{-\infty }^0 (1-y)^{b-1} (2-y)^{-a-b} \, _2F_1(1,d;c+d+1;y) \, dy$

Comment: What can you say about the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$?

Comment: For what its worth, you can estimate this function with Monte Carlo integration as well by noticing you have a beta distribution in the integrand.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson All of a,b,c,d are >1. Something I didn't mention in my original post is that this function is equal to XY/(XY+(1-X)(1-Y)) where X and Y are independent beta distributions (X with parameters a,b and Y with c,d). I thought that the problem would be solvable for anyone knowledgable about hypergeometrics. Now that I've learned more, I know that there isn't a set process to solve it because of the 2-1/x. Unfortunately, in order for this to be useful for me I need to compute it millions of times a second so anything that approximates it must approach the solution extremely quickly

Answer (score 1):

*Comment.*
For $$\int_0^1 (1-y)^{b-1} (2-y)^{-a-b} \, _2F_1(1,d;c+d+1;y) \, dy\tag1$$ I find an "almost" match.

Gradshteyn & Ryzhik 7.512.9 is
\begin{align} &
\int_{0}^{1}\!{x}^{\gamma-1} \left( 1-x \right) ^{\rho-1} \left( 1-zx
 \right) ^{-\sigma}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(\alpha,\beta;\,\gamma;\,x)}
\,{\rm d}x
\\
&={\frac {\Gamma \left( \gamma \right) \Gamma \left( \rho
 \right) \Gamma \left( \gamma+\rho-\alpha-\beta \right)  \left( 1-z
 \right) ^{-\sigma}}{\Gamma \left( \gamma+\rho-\alpha \right) \Gamma
 \left( \gamma+\rho-\beta \right) }
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(\rho,\sigma,\gamma+\rho-\alpha-\beta;\,\gamma+\rho-\beta,\gamma+\rho-\alpha;\,{\frac {z}{z-1}})}
}
\end{align}
This yields
\begin{align} &
\int_{0}^{1}\!{x}^{c+d} \left( 1-x \right) ^{b-1} \left( 2-x \right) 
^{-a-b}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,d;\,c+d+1;\,x)}\,{\rm d}x
\\ &
={\frac {\Gamma
 \left( c+d+1 \right) \Gamma \left( b \right) 
}{\Gamma \left( c+d+b
 \right)  \left( c+b \right) }}\;
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(b,a+b,c+b;\,c+1+b,c+d+b;\,-1)}
\end{align}
But because of the $x^{c+d}$ in there, it does not match $(1)$.

---

*Gradshteyn, I. S.; Ryzhik, I. M.; Zwillinger, Daniel (ed.); Moll, Victor (ed.)*, [**Table of integrals, series, and products. Translated from the Russian. Translation edited and with a preface by Victor Moll and Daniel Zwillinger**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123849335), Amsterdam: Elsevier/Academic Press (ISBN 978-0-12-384933-5/hbk; 978-0-12-384934-2/ebook). xlv, 1133 p. (2015). [ZBL1300.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1300.65001).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the source you are using or how comprehensive it is. Since you couldn't find a match do you think that means it's likely there is no solution?